# Why are some plastics flexible at low temperatures and some not?

Tags: material-science

Is there any general predictors for the flexibility of plastics as the temperature drops?

Comment: Possibly a question which chemists might be better at answering?  One important factor is the flexibility of the chain molecules which make up the plastic.

Comment: Chain length, cross linking, uniformity in chain length, plasticizer content, chain alignment, ...  Very complex business (at least to me, not a polymer person). Chemistry SE might help, but they tend to be much more chemists, not polymer folks.